# Why i can't use absolute path in scss react

Tags: reactjs, sass, module, path

My fonts is inside public/fonts/roboto directory

This is my fonts.scss file in src/styles

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    src: url('/fonts/roboto/roboto-regular.ttf');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

And this is my index.scss file in src/styles

```
@import './mixins';
@import './fonts';
@import './global';
```

When i try to use

```
src: url('/fonts/roboto/roboto-regular.ttf');
```

Instead of this

```
src: url('../../public/fonts/roboto/roboto-regular.ttf');
```

It gives me an error

```
ERROR in ./src/styles/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[3]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[4]!./src/styles/index.scss) 5:36-98
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/roboto/roboto-regular.ttf'
```

Why i can't use absolute path?
React version is 18 with typescript (cra), maybe i don't know something?